# Add gaussian noise in a radius around a point

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gaussian, matplotlib-3d

Given a point `(x, y)`, how would I create `n` random points that their distance from `(x, y)` is gaussian distributed with `sigma` and `mean` as a param?

Answer (score 9):

For the 2-D distribution use [`numpy.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html). The trick is that you need to get the distribution for each dimension. So for example for a random distribution around point (4,4) with sigma 0.1

**Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `scipy 1.10.1`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `numpy 1.24.3`**

```
sample_x = np.random.normal(4, 0.1, 500)
sample_y = np.random.normal(4, 0.1, 500)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(sample_x, sample_y, '.')
fig.show()
```

[image]

You can accomplish the same thing with [`numpy.random.multivariate_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html#numpy.random.multivariate_normal) as follows:

```
mean = np.array([4,4])
sigma = np.array([0.1,0.1])
covariance = np.diag(sigma ** 2)
x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, covariance, 1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, '.')
```

For the 3-D distribution you can use [`scipy.stats.multivariate_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

x, y = np.mgrid[3:5:100j, 3:5:100j]
xy = np.column_stack([x.flat, y.flat])
mu = np.array([4.0, 4.0])
sigma = np.array([0.1, 0.1])
covariance = np.diag(sigma ** 2)
z = multivariate_normal.pdf(xy, mean=mu, cov=covariance)
z = z.reshape(x.shape)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a multi variate normal distribution.  For your case, you have to use a normal distribution both on the X and Y axis.  If you plot the distribution, it will be a 3 dimensional bell curve.

Use numpy's multivariate normal distribution.

```
numpy.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov[, size])

mean : 1-D array_like, of length N
Mean of the N-dimensional distribution.
cov : 2-D array_like, of shape (N, N)
Covariance matrix of the distribution. It must be symmetric and positive-semidefinite for proper sampling.
size : int or tuple of ints, optional
Given a shape of, for example, (m,n,k), m*n*k samples are generated, and packed in an m-by-n-by-k arrangement. Because each sample is N-dimensional, the output shape is (m,n,k,N). If no shape is specified, a single (N-D) sample is returned.
Returns:    
out : ndarray
The drawn samples, of shape size, if that was provided. If not, the shape is (N,).
In other words, each entry out[i,j,...,:] is an N-dimensional value drawn from the distribution.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.random.normal` to pull random numbers from a Gaussian distribution for the new x and y coordinates.

```
from numpy.random import normal

sigma = 1.0
point_0 = (0.0, 0.0)

point_1 = [i + normal(0, sigma) for i in point]
```

This works in this case because multiplying a Gaussian distribution in the x and y dimensions will give a Gaussian distribution in the radial dimension.  I.E. `exp(-r^2/a^2) = exp(-x^2/a^2) * exp(-y^2/a^2)`