# Visualizing a multivariate normal distribution in 3 Dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, surface, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to visualise a multivariate normal distribution with matplotlib.  I would like to produce something like this:

[image]

I use the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
x = np.linspace(-1, 3, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean = [1, 2], cov = np.array([[0.5, 0.25],[0.25, 0.50]]), size = 100000)
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_title('surface');
```

But I get the following error message:

```
...
      7 ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
----> 8                 cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
...
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

What is the reason of the error and how my code could be corrected?

Comment: Shouldn't `Z` be a function of `x, y` pairs? Like illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9170879/8881141). Atm you probably created a different array size for Z.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have done this with [`scipy.stats.multivariate_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html), using the `pdf` method to generate the z values. As @Piinthesky pointed out, the numpy implementation returns the x and y values for a given distribution. An example using the scipy version is found in [Python add gaussian noise in a radius around a point [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636191/python-add-gaussian-noise-in-a-radius-around-a-point/43636583#43636583):

**Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `scipy 1.10.1`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `numpy 1.24.3`**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-1, 3, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
pos = np.dstack((X, Y))
mu = np.array([1, 2])
cov = np.array([[.5, .25],[.25, .5]])
rv = multivariate_normal(mu, cov)
Z = rv.pdf(pos)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
fig.show()
```

[image]